# Is it possible to use Angular for Server Side Includes (SSI)?

Tags: .net, angular, server-side-includes

I have little to no experience with Server Side Includes. I have read on the internet that you can work best without libaries/frameworks if you work with Server Side Includes. To avoid dependencies.

But I am still curious what the possibilities are with Angular. For this I made a proof of concept with Angular for SSI. It is an Angular widget that shows a header with a menu. To make the PoC available to the outside world, I created a MVC page in .NET that looks like this:

```
<app-ssi-poc></app-ssi-poc>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dev.example.nl/js/poc/styles.css?@Html.GetVersion()" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dev.example.nl/js/poc/runtime.js?@Html.GetVersion()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dev.example.nl/js/poc/polyfills.js?@Html.GetVersion()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dev.example.nl/js/poc/main.js?@Html.GetVersion()"></script>
```

The external website can access the page and the widget is displayed correctly.

But an other Angular instance is also used on some pages on the external website. Now I get the following error message that NgZone is already loaded. I have tried not to include my polyfills file, but that doesn't work either.

Is it possible to run two angular instances on the same page? Where they both have a different runtime, polyfills, ng zone, etc.?

Or

Should i stop being so stubborn and make it without libraries/frameworks :)

Thank you in advance.